# bytearray in extra breaking return

Tags: android, android-intent

Having a little trouble when trying to return a byte array from an activity. The return code is:

```
private void returnLocation(byte[] mapImage) {

    Intent intent = new Intent();       
    intent.putExtra("mapImage", mapImage);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

    finish();
}
```

EDIT: This is how I call and try to receive it in the parent activity:

```
....
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ChildActivity.class);
ParentFragment.this.startActivityForResult(i, 255);
...
```

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

```
    if(requestCode == 255) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {               
            mImage = data.getByteArrayExtra("mapImage");                
        }
    }
}
```

I've a breakpoint on the onActiviyResult that never gets hit when i try returning a byte array.

However, when trying to return the intent it goes back to the first activity (not the one that called it). I can't see anything that suggests a problem in the logger.

If I change the Extra value to '5' (an integer), it returns fine.

Is there something I'm missing when trying to pass back a byte array?

Thanks

Comment: please post how you fetch the extras in the second Activity

Comment: That's the problem though, it doesn't hit the second activity when a byte array is passed. It does if an integer is passed.

Comment: and it propably depends on the code of the second activity....

Comment: I've added the code. There's a breakpoint on the onActivityResult which never gets hit when returning a bye array, but does if I return an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has a limit on the size of a `Bundle`, which is what the `Intent` uses internally. If the data exceeds the bundle size it will display `ERROR/JavaBinder(7881): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!` in the logs, but it won't throw an exception.

Try writing the byte array to a temp file and passing the file name in the Intent.

Comment: Great, that's what the issue was thanks! The image was too big.

Following on from what you suggested, Am I worrying over nothing about the performance when saving an image to a temp file then immediately reading it back into memory in the parent activity?

Comment: That is what I do in my app :) Just make sure you **delete the temp file** after you are done with it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that you are calling startActivityForResult(i, 255) from a Fragment.

Instead of calling ParentFragment.this.startActivityForResult(i, 255);

you should call : startActivityForResult(i, 255);

If the above approach doesnt work, try the following:

Since the Activity that is hosting your fragment gets onActivityResult() result so you need to override activity's onActivityResult(), call super.onActivityResult() in your fragment to propagate to respective fragment for unhandled results codes or for all.

Comment: The `ChildActivity` must call finish to pass the data back to the calling activity.

Comment: @AesSedai101 , I am sorry for my previous answer, My mistake. Check my edited answer.